# MongoDB findOneAndUpdate returns document that doesn't match the filter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to setup a findOneAndUpdate operation that will update a document if it matches 2 filters:

```
    const existingUser = await  this.userModel.findOneAndUpdate({id: id, accountId: acc._id},{$set: {name, properties}}, { new: true});
```

But Mongo is behaving very weirdly. In the example above, there is no document that matches the filters, so none should be returned, correct?

For some weird reason, it returns a document that matched the `id` condition. Even though that specific document does not have a `accountId` property.

This is the only document I have in the DB:

```
{
    "_id": "62987cceb0b3b13477efa888",
    "id": "7",
    "name": "Some Name",
    "properties": {
        "age": "39"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

When I set moongoose debug to true, I see this in the logs:

```
Mongoose: users.findOneAndUpdate({ id: '7' }, { '$set': { name: 'Luis Novo', properties: Map(1) { 'age' => '39' } } }, { upsert: false, remove: false, projection: {}, returnDocument: 'after', returnOriginal: false})
```

For some reason, it is not sending the second parameter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share some sample data

Comment: findOneAndUpdate takes three parameters: filter, update, options.
In the example, you're passing options as the second parameter.

I see that you're using mongoose, try adding mongoose.set('debug', true); before your findOneAndUpdate and look at the logs to know what exactly gets sent to the MongoDB server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the *debug* logs, mongoose isn't sending the `accountId` in your filter.

Make sure you have `accountId` added to your schema, or set [`strictQuery`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strictQuery) to `false` to tell mongoose to send fields that do not exist on your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. My Model did not contain the field name "accountId". Upon adding the field, it fixed the problem.